# How to return fluently?

Tags: c#, method-chaining

I'm becoming addicted to writing fluently (perhaps incorrectly originally said "declaratively") and I'm taking it to possibly unwise extremes, but the more I write this way the more one thing stands out as being completely unable to write in this fashion, and that's the `return` statement.

Something like what I want to write (for example):

```cs
StartSomewhere
.Get<Something>()
.OrderBy(something => something.SomeProperty)
.Transform(ToSomethingElse)
.ChooseSomeOption("some value")
.Run()
.ReturnIfNull() // impossible!
.ContinueUsingNonNullValue();
```

What I'm stuck with instead:

```cs
if (
   StartSomewhere
   .Get<Something>()
   .OrderBy(something => something.SomeProperty)
   .Transform(ToSomethingElse)
   .ChooseSomeOption("some value")
   .Run()
   .IsNull(out var notNullValue)
)
   return;

if (
   notNullValue
   .ContinueUsingNonNullValue()
   // etc.
)
   return;
```

I suspect there's no way to get what I want here besides doing something really advanced and crazy like wrapping everything in an `Abortable` monad or something so that the chain can be turned off midway, allowing the remaining calls to just be ignored, so maybe it's pointless to ask, but who knows.

Comment: Is this really declarative? or is it really procedural: Step 1 Get something; Step 2 sort it; Step 3 change it; Step 4 make a selection ...

Comment: @jmarkmurphy yes, my code may not be strictly "declarative".

Comment: Do you mean you want a "fully *[fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C#)*" interface? ... What you have here doesn't read like declarative code to me.

Comment: @svidgen yes, maybe I mean fluent and not declarative, sorry.

Comment: I guess you could throw an exception

Comment: @jmarkmurphy if you delete the dots at the start of the lines and add semicolons at the end it would still read as legal code. If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck........

Comment: You are getting used to the 'pipeline' way of doing things and the tail/end step always decides the return value. Also, conditionals don't go well with this style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine what your code would look like if you could have fluent if methods....

```
DoSomething()
  .If(true)
  .Step2()
  .Else()
  .Step3()
  .EndIf()
  .Step4()
```

Would you really be happy with this?

You could achieve it with some internal state object. But its not any more readable, and if we throw in some nesting its only going to get worse.

You can improve on your current method by keeping the object. Allowing you to move the code blocks out of the if statement.

```
var i = DoSomething()
    .Step1()

if(i.Result() != null) 
{
     i.Step2(); 
}
```

Comment: I think you're right, it just turns things into a mess.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving the editorial aside *for a moment*, two options come to mind:

**1. Always operate on a "collection" or "builder".**

Instead of having `ChooseSomeOption(<string>)` return a scalar, *always* return a `TypeCollection`. (Same for *every method in the chain.*) Your fluent interface just exists in some sort of `TypeCollection` class then. And, if a `filter()` or `remove()`-type operation reduces the `Count` to `0`, *it doesn't matter.* **Everything *just works*.**

If a non-`Collection` return value is required, just make it your last "build" step.

<sup>And as alluded to, it doesn't strictly need to be a collection. It could just sort of be a ["builder."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#C#)</sup>

**2. Use the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern#C#).**

Basically, if a method like `ChooseSomeOption(<string>)` doesn't find a matching `ChainLink` object, return a `new NullChainLink()`, a child class of `ChainLink` that supports the same methods as a real `ChainLink`, but doesn't actually *do* anything.

This *might* get more complicated than option 1, because you'll need to create null objects for every possible nullable response *and every type thereafter*, which much *also* be "nullable."

---

I think I'd remiss if I didn't include the editorial:

I really like fluent interfaces. But, if I'm being honest with myself *and you*, they're *really really **really*** annoying to debug. A *significant* number of fluent interfaces I've written over the years were very pleasant to write, and *very easy to **read***, but ultimately broken apart during debugging efforts.

If you and your team like this sorts of method chaining, two pieces of advice:

1. Don't make sacrifices for it.
2. Write unit tests *obsessively*.

Even with a lot of testing, it's *probably* better to sacrifice an "elegant" method chain for *code that works **right now*** than it is to restructure *everything else* to make your fluent interface work.

Comment: this kind of code mostly only exists at the topmost (UI) level. it's not working 100% on fluent objects. what I've done is written two extension methods `With` and `SelectWith` that run either an `Action` or a `Func` on the current value. this allows you to treat any `Action` or `Func<T>` as if it was a fluent method. I've sort of solved my problem with returning by instead conditionally calling a local method. the main problem is that it seems to require parameters since I can't carry everything forward. I don't think it's prone to bugs since the methods are each individually very simple.

Comment: `With` and `SelectWith`?? ... Are you in danger of reinventing the [Linq `Enumerable` interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2)???

Comment: No, they aren't `IEnumerable` methods. `void With<T>(this T o, Action<T> a) => a(o);` and `T2 SelectWith<T1, T2>(this T1 o, Func<T1, T2> f) => f(o);` `SelectWith` could be called `Transform`. Or they're kind of like `.ForEach` and `.Select` except they operate on single objects instead of sequences/enumerables.

Comment: One example: instead of `Console.WriteLine("this is some text");` now you can write `"this is some text".With(Console.WriteLine);`. That's a simple example that you might not like, but it's much better when `"this is some text"` is the result of a long chain of methods.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is invert the condition and write some `If...` extension methods. Rather than say "Cancel if condition", I say "do this if not condition".

The main reason to cancel is to avoid nesting (specifically the indentation), but you can still avoid nesting by extracting the actions into named nested methods. This splits the logic up into named chunks which seems like it might actually be beneficial.

This probably wouldn't work if I needed to return a value, though.

```
void MyMethod() {
   StartSomewhere
   .Get<Something>()
   .OrderBy(something => something.SomeProperty)
   .Transform(ToSomethingElse)
   .ChooseSomeOption("some value")
   .Run()
   .IfNotNull(continueUsingNonNullValue);

   void continueUsingNonNullValue(object nonNullValue) =>
      nonNullValue
      .DoSomethingWithValue()
      .DoSomethingElseWithValue()
      // etc.
}
```

This ultimately proved a bit too messy/smelly. It was interesting, though, since it broke apart a method into smaller sections, each of which with it's own descriptive name. But it became harder to understand exactly what the function was doing as a whole. In particular it wasn't obvious where and when the logic would or wouldn't continue.

What I've done instead is make (good?) use of `out var`. Rather than wrap the chain itself in an `if`, and rather than writing the same `var result =`, `if (result == null) return;` code over and over and over, I use a method that can be used like this:

```
StartSomewhere
.Get<Something>()
.OrderBy(something => something.SomeProperty)
.Transform(ToSomethingElse)
.ChooseSomeOption("some value")
.Run()
.IsNull(out var value, out var isNull);

if (isNull)
   return;

// continue using non-null value
```

With Resharper `ContractAnnotation` I get warnings if the value is not known to be not-null and I try to use it anyway. I think anything more would require adding something new to the language.

Answer (score -1):

There's two approaches you can take here, both of which I've used successfully in the past: one using state, one not.

**Using state**

Assuming that your whole fluent chain used just one object, `MyFluentType`, then `ReturnIfNull` would do something like:

```
MyFluentType ReturnIfNull()
{
    inReturnNullState = SomeNullTest();
    return this;
}
```

and `ContinueUsingNonNullValue` does something like:

```
MyFluentType ContinueUsingNonNullValue()
{
    if (!inReturnNullState)
    {
        // do whatever the method does as we aren't in that state
    }
    return this;
}
```

So `ContinueUsingNonNullValue` is always called, and it uses the object's current state to determine whether it does something or just returns.

**No state solution**

Here, we have `MyFluentType` implement an interface, `IFluentType`. Then `ReturnIfNull` decides which implementation of `IFluentType` to return. If it's `null`, it returns an implementation that has an empty `ContinueUsingNonNullValue`:

```
class MyFluentType : IFluentType
{
    IFluentType ReturnIfNull() => SomeNullTest() ? new NullFluentType(this) : this;

    MyFluentType ContinueUsingNonNullValue()
    {
        // do whatever the method does as we aren't in that state
        return this;
    }
}

class NullFluentType : IFluentType
{
    private readonly MyFluentType _parent;
    NullFluentType(MyFluentType parent) => _parent = parent;        

    MyFluentType ContinueUsingNonNullValue() => _parent;
}
```

This way, no state is needed. Instead, a different type, with a different implementation of `IFluentType` is provided, depending on the null check.

Neither solution "returns" at the `ReturnIfNull` point; they simply bypass any further processing so effectively end the chain and return at that point, even if in reality they don't.